# Leaflet tooltip won't animate correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I need to animate tooltip binded permanently to marker (using transition CSS3), the marker is animated well but the tooltip is animated at the first time from the top left map to the marker. How to avoid this behavior?

[Demo of the issue](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/vize/edit?html,css,console,output)

Comment: If you want to animate only opacity use `transition: opacity 4.0s linear`. If you really want to animate positioning, then place the tooltip to its starting position before animate it.

Comment: the tooltip is binded to the marker, it moves with it, I don't choose to move it. I just add a class so I'll have the transition animation. I need the move animation and not the opacity one. Try to click on Test button on my demo link

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** try the updated code(switching over classes to get the desired result)

```css
.anim-tooltip{
  transition: opacity 4.0s linear;
}
.anim-tooltip-custom{
  transition: all 4.0s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Leaflet JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    #map {
      width:600px;
      height:400px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="test()">TEST</button>
  <div id='map'></div>


  <script>
    // Remember to include either the Leaflet 0.7.3 or the Leaflet 1.0.0-beta1 library

    var myCenter = new L.LatLng(50.5, 30.51);
    var map = new L.Map('map', {center: myCenter, zoom: 15});

    var positron = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    var marker = new L.Marker(myCenter);
    map.addLayer(marker);
    marker.setIcon(L.icon({   
      iconUrl:"https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
            className: 'anim-custom'
        })); 
    
    
    marker.bindTooltip("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amescing elit",{
                permanent: true,
                offset : [10,-20],
                direction : "right",
                className: 'anim-tooltip'
        }).openTooltip();

     var test = function(){
    marker.bindTooltip().closeTooltip();
      marker._icon.className="anim-tooltip-custom";
      marker._tooltip._contentNode.className=marker._tooltip._contentNode.className.replace("anim-tooltip","anim-tooltip-custom");// update the class name with animate-custom
    marker.bindTooltip().openTooltip();
      marker.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(50.502,30.512));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I remove it it means I got no animation. My goal is to animate the marker and the tooltip on change there position. But without the first animation of the tooltip from the top left map to the marker.

Comment: @swahi-ems then replace `all` with `opacity` it will help to display with effect .

Comment: try to click on TEST button on the demo link, and you'll understand the animation I need, if I change to opacity, the tooltip will change it's position without animation

Comment: @swahi-ems check the update may be this is what you are looking for.